# Comparing two columns in an IF statement in a stored procedure in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, if-statement, stored-procedures

I have two different tables in SQL Developer, `TB_Temp` and `TB_Main`. I want to compare just two columns from these tables, so eg. I want to compare the `user_id` column in `tb_temp` and the `user_payment` column in `tb_main`.

Both these tables have been imported from Excel files. If there is a match, I want it to for instance, output just a debug using `dbms_output` logging.

So far I have; Its the comparison part I struggle with the `IF` statement! The two tables contain values which will constantly be uploaded with new information, therefore what I am getting at is I cant actually declare the values that are stored in the table, as they will always be changing if that makes sense? I just need to know if the columns match, then there needs to be an output!

```
create PROCEDURE PR_TEST AS

user_payment number;

CURSOR c is
SELECT user_payment 
FROM tb_main;

CURSOR tmp is

SELECT * 
FROM tb_temp
WHERE user_ref is null or user_ref = user_payment

cTemp%ROWTYPE

BEGIN

--loop through cursor---

 cTemp_COUNT:=0;

 FOR I IN cTemp LOOP

 end loop
```

Comment: In your comment to @Ghost you said the fields will be unknown.  Do you mean you need to flag if any field has a value that matches any other field?  Please can you edit your question to make it clear, what exactly you want to do.

Comment: @JonathanWillcock I edited my question to make it more clear

Comment: The values will change yes, but are the field names constant and is it only these two fields (user_payment and user_ref) that need to be compared?

Comment: @JonathanWillcock The User_payment (tb_main)and User_ref(tb_temp) remain constant and need to be compared in case of a potential match yes!

Comment: What is the result set you're after?  All records from both that match: all records from tb_main and related info from tb_temp?  Do you know what joins are?https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/

Comment: @xQbert - I would actually rather do them in If Statements rather than JOINS as I am doing the code with CURSORS and looping through the cursosrs

Comment: There's a time and a place for cursors.  Joining datasets is not one of them.  [See what Tom Says](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:73891904732164)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you know what joins are and ref_Cursors for your output?
Also note: when playing with imported data, you may have non-display characters such as space.  So if a user_Payment was '123' and a user ID was '123 ' no match would be found.

Shows all details from both tables where the user_payment matches user_ID

```
SELECT * 
FROM tb_Main M
INNER JOIN tb_temp T
 on M.user_payment = T.User_ID
```

Shows all records from both tables and when matches exist shows the records aligned (on same row) with eachother if multiple matches occur, multiple rows will be produced.

```
SELECT * 
FROM tb_Main M
FULL OUTER JOIN tb_temp T
 on M.user_payment = T.User_ID
```

Shows all records from tb_main and only details if it matches from tb_temp

```
SELECT * 
FROM tb_Main M
LEFT JOIN tb_temp T
 on M.user_payment = T.User_ID
```

Shows all records from tb_temp and only details if it matches from tb_main

```
SELECT * 
FROM tb_Main M
RIGHT JOIN tb_temp T
 on M.user_payment = T.User_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

The SET based solution should work for you.

```
SELECT t.* 
FROM tb_temp t INNER JOIN tb_main m on 
WHERE t.user_ref = m.user_payment
UNION
SELECT * FROM tb_temp WHERE user_ref IS NULL
```